# instalación de wordpress con dominio y host

Tags: wordpress

Buenas tardes,primero de todo no estoy seguro si es el lugar adecuado, si no es así ,pido disculpas.
 Me he puesto como objetivo crear una página web para ir subiendo contenido sobre mis proyectos de programación.
He contratado un dominio y un host para subir la página.
He descargado wordpress desde wordpress.org, he creado una nueva bbdd en mi host y logeado en phpmyadmin.
Ahora viene el problema, según veo en los tutoriales debo modificar el archivo wp-config.php con la información de mi bbdd (echo). Y he subido dicho archivo a mi host.
Como último paso de pide abrir "http://nombreDeminDominio/install.php" donde se iniciaría la instalación de wordpress ,pero no carga nada, no estoy seguro de donde esta el fallo y no paro de darle vueltas, ¿Qué debo hacer? Gracias de antemano.

Comment: Normalmente este tipo de errores se debe a que el directorio de subida del wordpress no es mismo que utiliza el servidor como directorio principal. Revisa esta configuración y si el directorio no es el mismo mueve los archivos y carpetas a la ruta buena. Siento no ser más concreto sobre la ruta, pero depende mucho de cada servidor de hosting y el tipo del mismo.

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu comentario , he visto que mi host incluye la instalación de un paquete dedicado a wordpress y lo he subido desde ahí, por otro lado he cambiado los dns ya que al tener el host por un lado y el dominio por otro no estaban bien definidos, solucionado . gracias de nuevo.